# JSLink does not load in Calendar view

Tags: calendar, jslink

I have a Calendar list. I added JSLinks to all views, and most of the files are loading as they should and they work ok. However in the Calendar view the *.js file is not loaded (the path to the file is correct). Is it possible to add a JavaScript file to Calendar view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSR is not available for the calendar webpart. The requirement for it has been expressed by several members of the SharePoint community and has been acknowledged by the SP dev team.